# Unable to write to cache in Django

Tags: django, graphite

On my graphite install, `/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/local_settings.py` contains:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

However, when bring up `http://<host>/graphite`,

I get this error from traceback:

```
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache'}}
```

Does anybody know where else should I look to set the Django cache?

This is the apache log:

```
[Thu Nov 06 11:50:53 2014] [error]   File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/cacheback/base.py", line 178, in cache_set
[Thu Nov 06 11:50:53 2014] [error]     type(data)))
[Thu Nov 06 11:50:53 2014] [error] RuntimeError: Unable to save data of type <type 'dict'> to cache
```

It looks like Django is not reading my `local_settings.py` for caching. Any ideas?

Comment: do the rest of settings in the local_settings.py file take effect?

Comment: @dukebody, like which entries?

Comment: Is your app actually making use of the correct settings file? By the sounds of it, your `local_settings.py` isn't being loaded (or is being loaded in the wrong order - overwriting your cache settings)

Comment: it is trying to read this file: /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django_cacheback-0.8-py2.6.egg/cacheback/base.py there is not such file. /usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/django_cacheback-0.8-py2.6.egg is a file not a directory.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony, everything else is retrieving its config from local_settings.py, I can see the calls in apache. For some reason, it is not reacing the cache settings correctly.

Comment: @dukebody, I've added these middle classes: 
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
but still not progress, is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: You don't have to add any middleware classes. Try to do the whole install again following proven instructions from scratch.

Comment: @dukebody, proven instructions where?

Answer (score 0):

In app_settings.py, it was set to dummy cache, I changed that to locmem. it worked.